# Can't add string variable as a function argument

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

i've mostly just been lurking around stackoverflow since i started learning javascript, but recently encountered a problem i can't seem to find a solution to.

I've got a container with 3 different icons, when either of the icons is clicked, it's supposed to add height and text to the parent container. Height change works, but i just can't add text. Texts differ from icon to icon.

Here's the HTML & JS code:

```
<section id="main-container">
            <section class="main-section" id="main-section-1">
                <div id=main-section-1-content>
                    <div id="icon-container">
                        <div id="icon-cycle"><img style="width: 150px" src="media/icon_bicycle.png" onclick="iconContainerAnimate(cycleText)">
                        </div>
                        <div id="icon-hike"><img style="width: 150px" src="media/icon_hiker.png" onclick="iconContainerAnimate(hikeText)"></div>
                        <div id="icon-canue"><img style="width: 150px" src="media/icon_canue.png" onclick="iconContainerAnimate(canueText)"></div>
                       <div id="icon-container-text">
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
        </section>
```

And here's the JS attached to it (the text attached is just experimental):

```
function iconContainerAnimate(icon){
                var cycle, canue, hike, iconContainer, iconContainerText, cycleText, canueText, hikeText 
                cycle = document.getElementById('icon-cycle');
                canue = document.getElementById('icon-canue');
                hike = document.getElementById('icon-hike');
                iconContainer = document.getElementById('icon-container');
                iconContainerText = document.getElementById('icon-container-text');
                cycleText = 'aaaaa';
                canueText = 'bbbbb';
                hikeText = 'ccccc';
                    if (iconContainer.style.paddingBottom === '30px'){
                            iconContainer.style.paddingBottom = '10vh';
                            iconContainer.style.transition = 'padding-bottom 1s ease';
                            iconContainerText.style.height = '20vh';
                            iconContainerText.style.transition = 'height ease-out 1s';
                            iconContainerText.appendChild(icon);

                    }   else{
                            iconContainer.style.paddingBottom = '30px';
                            iconContainer.style.transition = 'padding-bottom 1s ease';
                            iconContainerText.style.height = '0vh';
                            iconContainerText.style.transition = 'height ease-out 1s';
                    }
            }
```

I know i'm not familiar with function arguments that much, so i hope it ain't a dumb question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put single quotes around the string.  Otherwise, just like normal javascript, it is going to think they are variables.  `onclick="iconContainerAnimate('hikeText')"`

Comment: Though, your method logic is trying to do `appendChild(icon)` so that would suggest that the icon value should be a DOM Element, and not a string.  So what is going on there?

Comment: As you can see, all three images (bicycle, hike & canue) have different variables attached to them. What i want is - when a user clicks one of the icons - a text attached to that icon should appear. So the argument of the function is actually a variable, to which i want to attach a string, which is a <p> element. 

Your second comment explained a mistake i made tho - the hikeText is a string variable, so I tried changing it to a DOM element so i could use appendChild with it. But it gives the same error.

ncaught ReferenceError: cycleText is not defined
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick

Comment: I DID IT.

For some reason, the variables attached to the function (cycleText, hikeText and canueText) had to be defined OUT of the function. Do you know why that is?

Sorry if the questions are noobish, I still have a LOT to learn. :D

Comment: Anyways, I've got a new problem now - when the same icon is clicked twice everything goes right - first the text appears, then it disappears. But how do i make the container shrink and expand again, with different text, when i click a different icon then the first one?